# How to recover disk space used by mysql databases?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, diskspace

I am using Ubuntu for PHP/MySQL development. Ubuntu is installed on VM and unfortunately VM has been assigned very low disk space (40 GB).

After 1st startup the disk had more than 20 GB disk space available.

Over past week I had to import and delete the db.sql.gz file quite some times. Now I only have 50 MB disk space left. Even though I have deleted all the databases using phpmyadmin, I suspect they still use the disk space.

How can I recover this disk space?

Comment: *I suspect they still use the disk space.* [Why don't you confirm that assumption first...](http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @ta.speot.is: I am not sure how I can?